# iOS memory management?

Tags: ios, memory-management

In iOS, is there a way/ a tool to know how much memory an object uses when it is created while the app is running? Using the console for example.

Answer (score 1):

Instruments, included with Xcode Tools, can show you a lot of interesting information about your running application.

Comment: Yea but I know the tool (memory leak, performance tool) but how CAN you see for just obe object.

Answer (score 0):

Choose Run->Run with Performance Tool-> Object Allocations.
(Or whichever thing you want to monitor)

Comment: Cool i'll try 

Do not know if i need to make a new but i need to wait 20 minutes until posting a new one so maybe can someone tell me : when you instance a new objec. You create getters and setters using @property and @synthesize than @release but you can't do with nsInteger why ???

Comment: Floo, that's because NSInteger is not an object like NSString or NSArray. It's a bitness-independent wrapper for int, which is from C.